# Sql query: return true if all column values don't equal a value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have a table called Engine, with id as the primary key

```
id  engine_name
----------------
1       abc
2       def
```

and another table called EngineMode, with id as primary key and engine_name is a foreign key from the Engine table

```
id  engine_name   engine_type
------------------------------
1       abc        R
2       abc        -9
3       abc        S
4       abc        -9
5       abc        T
6       def        -9
7       def        -9
8       def        -9
```

I want to query all Engines and check if all the engine_types do not equal -9, then I want to return true (or 1 using a bit), and if all engine_types equal -9 then return false (or 0 using a bit)

This is the result I'm trying to query

```
id  engine_name   approved_engine_types
---------------------------------------
1       abc                1
2       def                0
```

Here is the SQL used to create the tables and insert the data

```
CREATE DATABASE test;
USE [test]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[engine](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [engine_name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_engine] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [id] ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
CONSTRAINT [UQ_engine] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
(
    [engine_name] ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[engine_mode](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [engine_name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [engine_type] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_engine_mode] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [id] ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[engine] ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_engine_engine_name] DEFAULT ('') FOR [engine_name]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[engine_mode] ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_engine_mode_engine_name] DEFAULT ('') FOR [engine_name]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[engine_mode] ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_engine_mode_engine_type] DEFAULT ('') FOR [engine_type]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[engine_mode] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_engine_mode_engine] FOREIGN KEY([engine_name]) REFERENCES [dbo].[engine] ([engine_name])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[engine_mode] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_engine_mode_engine] 
GO

USE [test]
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[engine] ([engine_name])
VALUES
('abc'), ('def')
GO

USE [test]
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[engine_mode] ([engine_name], [engine_type])
VALUES
('abc', 'R'), ('abc', '-9'), ('abc', 'S'), ('abc', '-9'), ('abc', 'T'), ('def', '-9'), ('def', '-9'), ('def', '-9')
GO
```

I have tried creating a view for this query but I wasn't able to figure it out. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Just as an aside, your foreign key would be much better defined as the primary key in the Engine table - `id`, not `engine_name`. Or, alternatively, Engine_Name could be the primary key (although integer keys are generally preferred).

Comment: I hope you never have to change an engine's name if you do "have" to keep that design; you're be in for a world of hurt if you do.

Comment: I based this example off the legacy database I work with. Someone else designed it like that and I agree it should be redesigned with engine_name as a primary key instead of id. On the bright side, engine_name is never changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `group by`:

```
select engine_name,
    max(case when engine_type = '-9' then 0 else 1 end) as approved_engine_types
from EngineMode
group by engine_name
```

If you wanted the corresponding row from the reference table, we can `join` or `apply`:

```
select e.*, em.*
from engine e
cross apply (
    select max(case when engine_type = '-9' then 0 else 1 end) as approved_engine_types
    from EngineMode em 
    where em.engine_name = e.engine_name
) em
```

Comment: A `WHERE` instead of `MAX(CASE` might be faster if you can hit an index, and possibly more idiomatic.

Comment: Works great, thanks so much! That cross apply operation seems pretty useful too

Answer (score 1):

You can use group by and subquery

```
select  
             id
            ,engine_name
            ,max(approved_engine_types) as approved_engine_types
from (

            select 
                         a.id  
                        ,a.engine_name  ,
                        case 
                            when [engine_type]='-9' then 0 else 1 
                        end  approved_engine_types

            from  [engine]  a
            inner join [engine_mode] b on a.engine_name=b.engine_name
)d
group by id,engine_name
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/VfDGD8MJ)

Comment: I tried out your solution first and it worked great! I would have chose this one but the other one seemed simpler. If I could upvote answers, I would upvote this one for sure